# Attached behavior binding to element in controltemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, controltemplate, attachedbehaviors

I am adding an attached behaviour to a slider which will cause it to scroll some content when the thumb is dragged and held over a specific region. (Can't use a straightforward IsMouseOver trigger as the Slider Thumb has MouseCapture.)

The behaviour has 3 properties:

```
    #region IsScrollHoverProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsScrollHoverProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                "IsScrollHover",
                                                typeof(Boolean),
                                                typeof(ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
    #endregion

    #region ScrollLeftRectProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollLeftRectProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                "ScrollLeftRect",
                                                typeof(Rectangle),
                                                typeof(ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion

    #region ScrollRightRectProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollRightRectProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                "ScrollRightRect",
                                                typeof(Rectangle),
                                                typeof(ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion
```

The IsScrollHoverProperty is being set to true when the user drags the slider, this is all done in the Slider's ControlTemplates.Triggers, and works correctly.

When it's set to true the callback is going to hook PreviewMouseEnterHandlers into the two Rectangles to detect when the mouse enters them.

The Rectangles in question are also defined in the Slider's controltemplate thusly:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle  Width="40" Fill="#AAAAAAAA" Name="ScrollLeftRect"/>

            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle  Width="40" Fill="#AAAAAAAA" Name="ScrollRightRect"/>
         </StackPanel>
```

The problem I have is binding these Rectangles to the attached ScrollRightRect and ScrollLeftRect Properties. I have tried a few things and suspect I have made a stupid binding error or am trying to do something not allowed. I am currently binding them in the controltemplate.triggers as follows:

```
        <Trigger Property="local:ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour.IsScrollHover" Value="False">

            <Setter Property="local:ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour.ScrollLeftRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=ScrollLeftRect}"/>
            <Setter Property="local:ScrollHoverAreaBehaviour.ScrollRightRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=ScrollRightRect}"/>

            <Setter TargetName="ScrollLeftRect" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ScrollRightRect" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
```

I know this Trigger is being tripped as the rectangles fill Red as expected. 
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong from these snippets?

Thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: Do your ScrollLeftRect/ScrollRightRect never get set? Are there any binding errors in the OutputWindow?

Comment: Using breakpoints they always show as null, the default. I get the follwing binding error: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ScrollRightRect'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Slider' (Name='MainSlider'); target property is 'ScrollRightRect' (type 'Rectangle'). I'm sure this is a straightforward error. But I have been looking at this for ages and just can't spot it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's confirm you're not doing anything wrong, and the problem has nothing to do with the attached behaviors.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="Yellow">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="theText" Text="Hello" />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ElementName=theText, Path=Text}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

This snippet should cause "Hello" to appear twice when I mouse over the button, but it doesn't, and I get the same error as you:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=theText'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

This is explainable - once the binding is set on the `Button`, it won't be able to find a control named 'theText', because the Button lives in a different [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).

## An alternative

Some WPF controls need to do something similar to you - they assume that a specific control exists in the tree that they will interact with. But they don't use properties - they use names.

Start by giving the controls a name - the convention is to use "PART_" prefix:

```
<Rectangle ... Name="PART_ScrollLeftRect" />
```

Now put code like this in your callback when `IsScrollHover` is set:

```
private static void IsScrollHoverSetCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var target = (Slider) d;
    if ((bool)e.NewValue == false)
        return;

    target.ApplyTemplate();
    var leftRectangle = target.Template.FindName("PART_ScrollLeftRect", target);
    var rightRectangle = target.Template.FindName("PART_ScrollRightRect", target);

    // Do things with the rectangles
}
```

Note that depending on when the `IsScrollHost` property is set, the template might not be ready yet. In that case, you might want to subscribe to the `Loaded` or similar event, and then call `ApplyTemplate()`.

Although it might seem more complicated, it has one nice benefit: the markup will be simpler. A designer using Blend won't have to remember to wire up those complicated triggers, they just have to name the controls correctly.

The use of the PART_ prefix is a WPF convention, and normally used along with the [TemplatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) attribute. An example of this is the TextBox. When you override the template of a `TextBox`, [it won't function until you add a control named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx) `PART_ContentHost`.

**Update: I just blogged about template parts here: http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-part-names**